# XSLT - select the child of an element where 1 child = 'x' and another child contains 'y'

Tags: xml, xslt, contains

I'm trying to select a particular child element of a row where another child element is equal to a certain value, and another child element contains a value. My XML looks as follows:

```
<row>
   <field1>HEAD</field1>
   <field2/>
   <field3>123,456,789,000</field3>
   <field4>hello</field4>
   <field5/>
</row>
```

My goal here is to get the value of `<field4/>` where `<field1/> = HEAD` and `<field3/> contains '789'`.

So far I've tried the following which doesn't seem to work:

```
<xsl:variable name="myVar" select="789"/>
<xsl:value-of select="row[field1 = 'HEAD' and contains(field3, $myVar)]/field4"/>
```

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "*Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong here?*" I suppose this is not why you asked, but one thing that stands out is that if `<field3>' contains "6789" or 7890", your second test will return a false positive.

Comment: Thanks @michael.hor257k, I hadn't thought of that. Is there a way I can avoid this situation by perhaps looking through the comma separated list?

Comment: One way to avoid this is to define $myVar as `=',789,'` and test for `contains(concat(',', field3, ','), $myVar)`. Of course, things would be easier if your source data were normalized, thus adhering to the "one fact per field" rule.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that would only work though if `789` wasn't in the first or last position? Where it would appear as `789,` or `,789` respectively

Comment: No, it would work in all cases - try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your variable setup - it should be `select="'789'"` if you want to assign the literal `'789'`:

```
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="myVar" select="'789'" />
      <xsl:value-of select="row[field1 = 'HEAD' 
                          and contains(field3, $myVar)]/field4"/>
   </xsl:template>
```

**Edit** : To Clarify

```
  <xsl:variable name="myVar" select="z123" />
```

Will assign the value of the element `z123` (i.e. `789` if the document looked as follows)

```
<row>
   <z123>789</z123>
   <field1>HEAD</field1>
```

Whereas

```
  <xsl:variable name="myVar" select="'z123'" />
```

Assigns the literal `z123`. <del>I'm guessing the reason why a raw `789` works is because xml elements cannot start with a number and the parser is assuming a literal instead.</del> See @michael's explanation on WHY the numeric literal works.

Comment: I am guessing it works because (1) you **can** bind a variable to a *number*; and (2) the contains() function expects a *string* argument, and converts the supplied number implicitly.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code in the following stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="myVar" select="789"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="row[field1 = 'HEAD' and contains(field3, $myVar)]/field4"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and it works fine, it outputs `hello`

Comment: Thanks @Joel, I've just tried again in a different validator and it seems to have worked. Not sure what went wrong there!